# Which subalgebras $A$ of the matrix algebra $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ satisfy $C(C(A)) = A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, representation-theory

(Algebras are associative with unity in this question. They are not necessarily commutative.)

Given an $\mathbb{R}$-subalgebra $S$ of an algebra $A$, write $C(S)$ for the $\mathbb{R}$-algebra of all $t \in A$ such that for all $s \in S$ we have $st = ts$. We always have $C(C(A)) \supseteq A$ as a consequence of general facts about Galois connections.

> **Question.** Which subalgebras $S$ of the matrix algebra $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ satisfy $C(C(S)) = S$?

**Idea.** I was thinking of looking at linear subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and decomposing each element of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a sum of something in that subspace and something in its orthogonal complement. Algebras of matrices that act on just one of these components might have the desired property (but I'm not sure). I also don't know if this is an exhaustive list.

In theory, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_centralizer_theorem) result should be helpful, but I can't understand what it's saying.

Comment: The semisimple subalgebras have this property, that is, products of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$, $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, and $M_n(\mathbb{H})$. I'm not aware of any others off the top of my head, and plausibly those are the only ones.

Comment: von Neumann's bicommutant theorem?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I'm not sure I understand your comment. How are they subalgebras?

Comment: Sorry, the $n$ there was not supposed to be the same index as your $n$. Is that your confusion?

Comment: Well, I don't really understand how they're subalgebras of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$... (where $n$ refers to the $n$ in the question).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan the subalgebra generated by a nilpotent matrix of rank $n-1$ is equal to its commutant, hence to its bicommutant.